# Do I need to implement a Navigation controller in order to add views from other controllers?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, sdk, uiviewcontroller

When user taps on a button, I am displaying a whole new view (administration purposes)

```
AdminViewController *adminView = [[AdminViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AdminView" bundle:nil];
        [self.view addSubview:adminView.view];
        [adminView release];
```

In the view that I am pushing I have an IBAction with a close button. Basically, when I hit the close button, I want to destroy that second view and go back to my original one.

I can't use self.view removeFromSuperview because that will pretty much remove everything I have in the window. What do you guys think I need to do?

Comment: Have you tried [self.view popViewControllerAnimated:YES];?

Comment: I don't have a NavigationController set up. I was wondering if I could still achieve something similar without creating a NavigationController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this setup is an ideal candidate for

```
AdminViewController *adminView = [[AdminViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AdminView" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:adminView animated:YES];
[adminView release];
```

when the close button is pressed, you can do

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

on either view controller to make it disappear.

Comment: There we have it! Thanks a lot. I wasn't sure whether or not I was forced to create a navigation controller for what I wanted. You just made me smile :)